# USB to FTDI connection

Tags: usb, differential, high-speed, ftdi, signal-routing

I try to connect USB 2.0 to a FTDI FT2232HL. This is my first high speed layout.

I am planning to use 2-layer board 1.6 mm. I know that I have to keep 50 Ω Z0 and 90 Ω Zdiff. However with the 2-layer board it is not that convenient.

I read in the article that if I keep connection less than one inch than I can neglect the impedance and differential pair length.

Would it be fine in my case to route USB to FTDI connection like this?

And would the Vias bring me the troubles?

Also, is it better to do a 25 mm equal lines or 4.6 mm and 9 mm like in my case?

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be a two-layer board? Anyway, does the FT2232 *require* USB high speed? If you can just use full speed or especially low speed you can get away with much sloppier impedance matching.

Comment: It says that it is High speed and full speed compatible. So I guess that might be ok

Comment: Then if your application doesn't require high-speed speeds, you can run at full-speed and have less to worry about. I'd say try to make it work at high-speed anyway (just for practice if nothing else), and fall back on full-speed if it doesn't.

Comment: And what about FTDI own reference design layout? What does it say?